# Can I make Custom FaceBook's Light Box of "Connect with Facebook to Continue" and "This site requires that you Connect with Facebook."?

Tags: authentication, facebook

[image: http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3338/4564960137_0d3c09192d_o.png]

can we change text in this lightbox

want to change "This site requires that you Connect with Facebook." and "Connect with Facebook to Continue"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about doing this with the JavaScript SDK, but I know you can do it with the PHP one.

You would have to create your box you want displayed in HTML and CSS. When you generate it in your page you have the server make the action of clicking on the button direct the user to the location provided by $facebook->getLoginUrl();

This would essentially do what you want. As i said i am unsure if the same thing is accomplish-able with the JavaScript SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
here what i am doing 

in "facebooklogin.aspx" is first page for login after login and permissions user redirect to xxx.aspx page where i am fetching user details.

-- facebooklogin.aspx

<head runat="server">
    <title>FaceBook Login</title>
    <script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php/en_US"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function fblogin()
    {    
        //<![CDATA[
            //Replace API key with yours from Facebook
            var api_key = 'XXX';
            var channel_path = 'xd_receiver.htm';

            FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function() {
                // Create an ApiClient object, passing app's API key and 
                // a site relative URL to xd_receiver.htm
                FB.Facebook.init(api_key, channel_path);
                FB.ensureInit(function() {
                    FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("email,user_birthday,user_location", function(perms) {
                        if (!perms) {
                            //alert("No");
                        } else {
                            //alert("yes");
                            window.location ="http://xxx.aspx"
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        //]]> 
    }   
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="divbtnfb">
        <a onclick="javascript:fblogin();">login</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>


--CODE BEHIND in XXX.aspx

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ConnectAuthentication.isConnected())
            {
                //Create instance of REST api using current authanticated session
                Api api = new Api(CurrentSession);
                //Display user data captured from the Facebook API.
                try
                {
                    Facebook.Schema.user user = api.Users.GetInfo();
                    firstName.Text = user.first_name;
                    lastName.Text = user.last_name;
                    //for email use client code
                }
                catch
                {
                    Response.Redirect("facebooklogin.aspx");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("facebooklogin.aspx");
            }
}


-- In facebooklogin.aspx its checking for permission, if user is not loggedin to facebook this script shows this lightbox.
I want to change this lightbox
```